# How do i fetch the text from a <svg> tag which contains the tag text

Tags: selenium

I wanted to fetch text from the g tag and wanted to disply on concsol.
Total 21 rows and when i am clicking on it its give me popup(its not java or window based popup) I wanted to fetch some of the values from that pop and wanted to display on console.

After clicking on popup, contains 3 rows. Each row contains 3 td tag.  The value of the first td tag displayed but finding difficulty to fetch the value of second td tag.

Here is Code:

```
<td style=" "        > Manager</td>
<td style="padding-right">
    <svg  width="100%" hight="50%"  id=" ">
        <g>
            <defs....>...</defs>
            <rect....>...</rect>
            <text x="10"  y="24" fill=" " syle=" ">30%</text>
                 </g>
         <g>
            <text x="10"  y="24" fill=" "  syle=" ">70%</text>
            <text x="10"  y="24" fill=" " syle=" ">80%</text>

         </g>
    </svg>
<td>
```

It has displayed 'Manager' on console but finding difficulty to print the text "30%", 70% and 80% on console.

This is the path which showing one element.

```
//div[@id='performanceMeasureDetailsModel']//div[2]//table[1]//tbody[1]//tr[1]//td[2]//* [name()='svg']//*[name()='g'][1]//*[text()='50%']
```

giving required element but text can be vary so what woulds be dynamic path for it. Same way wanted to print value of second g tag,  and for all 21 rows.

If anybody knows how to fetch text tag contains text? Will be a great help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your url? Which selenium language it is binding?

Comment: Sorry, as per security policy i can not share the url. I can check for you and tell more detail about code. Its selenium with Java and trying to execute in Chrome.

Comment: @Provide some more HTML then?Did you check the below answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below `xpath`.This should identify all 21 elements.

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='text']
```

To get all elements text

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);         
List<WebElement> Items=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//*[name()='svg']//*[name()='text']")));
        for(int i=0;i<Items.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(Items.get(i).getText());

        }
```

Comment: yesd its giving me 24 elements which includes that 21 elements

Comment: @dh.purvi : So its resolved your problem then right?

Comment: Its not resolved yet, wanted to fetch those values, mentioned in my question. Just let me check

Comment: Whats the problem? Use WebdriverWait

Comment: @dh.purvi : Try the updated answer and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Sure,  will take some time for checking, after clicking on one pop up, it will fetch 4 to 5 text, then popup get closed and then new popup will get open again it will fetch  4 to 5 text and so on, that way all 35 elements will get display with 21 rows/popup.

Comment: Agreed your code will give 35 elements but how do i fetch 4-5 or 1 element from each popup. that logic have to be fixed.

Comment: @dh.purvi : without getting knowledge of your application how do you expect complete solution here.We can guide you only.

Comment: You are right! I updated  my vote. Please let me know if we can paste screenshot here. (I don't think so its allowed) WIll give you more idea about my question.

Comment: @dh.purvi : Yes you can't paste your screenshot here.what you could do you can paste it in your original post.

Comment: Ok, If this will not  solve as per my requirement, will post it new question with screenshot. Thanks. But your path/code is useful to me. Thanks.